# How was real-time browser chat implemented before WebSockets?

Tags: ajax, websocket, chat

Nowadays the go-to alternative for real-time browser-based chat rooms seems to be WebSockets. But I remember being in browser chat rooms way before WebSockets saw the light of day. Was it all just based on AJAX polling? Before that I'm assuming it was based on refreshing the actual page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were/are some alternatives:

- Simple HTTP pooling, e.g. every 5 seconds you make a GET request to get new messages from server. Not very good from traffic point of view.
- BOSH protocol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOSH_(protocol). This is some kind of WebSockets emulation on top of HTTP. I know some projects still use it.
- HTTP Long-polling

From what I see, BOSH protocol and HTTP Long-polling are still alive and used in some specific use cases.

Comment: Other options included Flash sockets, Java applets and the rarely used SSE (which pre-dates WebSockets).